# How can I check domains (and subdomains) entered by users vs my whitelist?

Tags: swift, whitelist

I'm looking for a SWIFT solution / function that will check if the entered url by a user is allowed by our system. (White listed).

It should also check for certain or any subdomains that domain might use as well.

for example, if I whitelist google.com, the following urls would return true.

google.com/xxxx 
mail.google.com/xxxxxx 
[any].google.com/xxxxxx

Any help please?

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find out the subdomain.

```
/(http:\/\/)?(([^.]+)\.)?google\.com/
```

Comment: thanks. i figured i'd need Regex but i was hoping to find an existing function i could use to pass urls into and have it return valid or not. 

I'll see if I can modify this and work on a function. thanks for this. it's a good start.